# How to get rows for each month separately in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `titas_clp_invoice_master` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_no` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_date` date NOT NULL,
  `amount` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `isdeleted` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_month` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_year` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;
```

Now I want something like this

Total transactions for each month of an year separately. Like 1 transaction for the Month of December 2015, 2 transactions for the month of January 2016, 3 transactions for the month of February 2016 etc.

Comment: what you tried yet. show your query?

Comment: which is the leading date field?

Comment: `GROUP BY` would help.

Comment: 4 transactions for month of march? 5 transactions for month of april?

Comment: Do you need months with a count of 0 listed?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's developers took quite some time to develop great [**date functions**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) - you should use them. There is no need for both `invoice_year` nor `invoice_month` as you already have `invoice_date` as a `date` formatted column. You can just use

```
SELECT invoice_date, count(*) 
FROM titas_clp_invoice_master
GROUP BY YEAR(invoice_date), MONTH(invoice_date)
```

Comment: Two cast is more expansive than the use of two columns, I don't understand how this answer got the upvote when it will show DATE - COUNT when he asked for another thing.

Comment: @sagi -- Most likely because it's correct usage and using a varchar column for a date is bad practice...